Script Help for overlapping edges between objects
I am working on a project that involves drawing grease pencil edges using the "mark freestyle edge" feature on edges that do not intersect with edges from other objects. I am using RBDLab to fracture objects, and I want to avoid marking the edges of these fractures as freestyle edges.
Essentially, when an object is fractured, and I add a grease pencil to the collection, line art appears at every fracture. I want to maintain the appearance of the object's normal outlines as if it wasn't fractured, at least until the fractures separate.
I've consulted with ChatGPT about whether this could be achieved by using a method involving the distance or bounding box over an edge. This method would detect if an edge between two objects shares very similar attributes like distance or potential collision via bounding box.
Here are screenshots showing intersections between objects:


I want to be able to mark these edges as "non-unique" and then mark every other edge that is not "non-unique" as "mark freestyle edge"
Here is the script that so far does mostly everything right but screws up a little.
First, this is what the original object looks like:

I marked out the edges I would like to "mark as freestyle edge".
Now here is the script outcome:

See, it MOSTLY works quite well (I kept messing randomly with the different thresholds, couldn't get something super consistent). I'm not sure what else I can do to make it work better as it gets all the right edges, but... all the internal edges are completely missed out as seen in the following example:

Now here is the script:

import bpy

print("Hello World")

And here is the blend file!
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/juxfpyhpoffvxui3bvtey/Low_Poly_Ship_Test.blend?rlkey=shmn9ut9z9fyyjo70y5glo7mp&st=xxvy1ik3&dl=0
If anyone can help me out with confidence, knowing that they can make this work, I'd be willing to pay you for your time, if the scripts work as I described it should and none of those lines are visible, I think 100-200 is fair. I absolutely need this script to be corrected/ changed to work, and I already think there is a great start.

PS. some extra notes-
An edge from 1 object may be 5 inches in length
An edge from a neighboring object might have 2 edges in a straight line that make up that 5 inch length, but almost like the edge is subdivided, this might be a reason a few edges might not be detected right
Also, maybe it would work better with planes? But that would take some trial and error
If anyone has any ideas at all, please let me know, I've tried geo nodes for a week now, and I'm completely stumped. Scripting using ChatGPT has been awful.
Thanks for reading, hope to hear from someone soon!

Please use the code insertion markdown instead of a screenshot of you script.

Will do as soon as I get to my computer!

I included the script in the blend file; it wouldn’t let me properly format it on stack exchange (I’m still a total noob here, is there any other way I can upload it? Maybe through drop box the same way as a notes file?

When you [edit] your message, you have multiple buttons at the top of the editor that help you format things. You can manually use the markdown syntax (which I prefer to use for inserting scripts), you can find a guide by clicking the ? icon on the right side of the editor toolbar. I edited your answer to give you an example of code insertion, please replace my mockup code by your own script. Then you will be able to remove the script's screenshot to avoid cluttering your question for nothing

As an extra side note: We have our own unofficial file sharing site: Blend-Exchange, which is more practical for us. I also advise you to check our share your file, it's full of good-to-know tips and explanations for sharing file here or any other website.
